# convert a callback function to RxJS

Tags: node.js, rxjs

I want to convert a piece of code from NodeJS Callback to RxJS but I am not sure I did it in the right way or not. I am keeping getting error.

Original code:

```
function signup(poolData, body) {
const { username, password, attributes } = body;
  userPool.signUp(username, password, attributes, null, (err, res) => {
    if (err) return cb(err);

    const cognitoUser = res.user;
    const data = {
      username: cognitoUser.getUsername(),
    };
    cb(null, data);
  });
}
```

Converted to RxJS:

```
function signup(poolData, body) {
    const { username, password, attributes } = body;
     return Observable.create( observer =>{
        let output = (err, res)=>{
          if(err) throw err;

          const cognitoUser = res.user;
          const data = {
            username: cognitoUser.getUsername(),
          };
          observer.next(data);
        }
        userPool.signUp(username, password, attributesList, null, output);
    });
}
```

I am calling my signup RxJS like this:

```
let observable = signup(poolData, params);
        observable
        .catch(err => print(`Error caught: ${err}`))
        .subscribe(val => print(val));
```

Can you advise me that did I convert the code correctly?
at the moment I receive the error that "TypeError: observable.catch is not a function".

Comment: Are you using RxJS 6+? You need to read up on pipeable operators if so; see e.g. https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/docs_app/content/guide/v6/migration.md

Comment: Maybe you need to use `pipe` method of Observable  and within it `catchError` operator, which is the RxJs way to control errors.

Comment: @jonrsharpe: yes I was using version 6+.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
let observable = signup(poolData, params);
observable.subscribe(val => print(val), err => print(`Error caught: ${err}`));
```

Subscribe method either takes a partial observer object ( `Object with next, error, complete methods [ Observer interface ]`) or three optional params as callbacks being next, error and complete functions in order.

`next`: Handler for each delivered value
`error`: Handler for an error notification
`complete`: Handler for completion of observable execution

Comment: Please provide your answer with a meaningful description.